Using Wilcoxon signed-rank test with a missing value
I’m working on a problem where I should use Wilcoxon signed-rank test, $9$ elements. One value of the ninth pair is missing, I only know that its outcome is negative. How should I treat that value? I've come to the info in the net, that “If there are missing values in the data range, the whole pair will be excluded in the analysis” but in case of the sign test I know that if we do not now the last entry but its sign is known, we can still use it. But in this case we have paired results so I'm not sure. I should complete the calculations by hand, not using R.
the differences are the following: $−7$, $−15$, $−1$, $−17$, $−10$, $−5$, $+11$, $−6$, $X_{9}<0$.
My guess is that I can leave it out since it's negative and it isn't different from the majority of the  $X_{i}$ values.

You have censored data. The R package NADA2 has the cen_signedranktest that allows for censored data. You might try that.

There are only so many possible ranks $|X_9|$ might have, & you know it's negative - have you considered investigating possible results?

No because Wilcoxon considers the values weights and I am clueless about how should I assign the ranks. I'm starting to wonder that maybe the professor tricks us and wants us to explain that it's not solvable with Wilcoxon signed rank test and use the simpler sign test to check the hypothesis. The question is whether WS-R test proves that the treatment gives negative outcome and since I know that 9th difference is negative and also the majority of values I thought that maybe there's a trick I don't notice to use.

(1) I don't know what you mean by "Wilcoxon considers the values weights". (2) If you don't know how to assign ranks for the Wilcoxon test you wouldn't be able to carry it out even without missing values, so learn that first. (3) I am trying to hint that you should be able to bound the test statistic & hence the p-value.

My opinion is that the signed rank test is obsolete and should be replaced by the rank difference test, which has multiple advantages: (1) Y-transformation invariant, (2) can be done with the proportional odds model, and (3) can handle partial data like yours.  See here for more information.

It's for a nonparametric statistics course and I was told to use Wilcoxon signed-rank test (by hand.)

Maybe you’ll get extra credit for mentioning the alternative test.

There are several issues at work here, so I will try to unwrap them.
First, the WSRt (Wilcoxon Signed Rank test) is not a test of the median, but a test of the pseudomedian (aka Hodges-Lehmann estimator (see wiki here, or here; if you or your professor can provide an intuitive interpretation to it, please share on CV; I would love to learn about it). If and only if the distribution is symmetric, then it becomes a test of the median (and, btw, also then of the mean or mode). And it is sensitive to departures from symmetry (to the point where actually it can be used as a good test of symmetry; testing against its observed median). But I am sure your professor asked you to estimate the median, and its CI. Your data is not very skewed, but nevertheless not really symmetric.
You also have a low sample size (8 known values, plus 1 unknown). The WSRt has pretty low power under these conditions. In fact, with only 6 values, WSRt will never return a significant result at the traditional $\alpha=0.05$ level (can not exceed the critical value). So using WSRt in these conditions, is a poor choice (I know, it is just an exercise, but nevertheless, would be nice to have "realistic" exercises). This is even made worse by the fact that your sample is not too "non-normal" ($p=.51 for Anderson-Darling), so a t-test would be much more appropriate.
@Frank Harell's suggestion to "obsolete" the WSRt brought a big smile to my face; I will happily 2nd the motion. If the WSRt is used to test the pseudomedian, it is not easily interpretable (which is why (almost?) no one uses it that way). And if used as a test of the median, it then is also a test of the mean etc.; and under assumption of symmetry, the CLT will converge quite rapidly, even with small sample sizes. So what is the true, real world applicability of the WSRt?
Now, finally, wrt your missing sample. One option is to simply exclude that pair; you only have 8 datapoints. Run WSRt (since your professor said so), and get a CI and/or p-value (be careful whether you want to run a single-sided test/CI or not...).
Alternatively, as suggested, you could try all possible ranks for this missing value. As you are told that it is negative, you have "only" 7 different ranks it could have. Try each, compute CI's/p-values for each, and see what you get.
But in fact, you only need to try the "worse case" scenario, i.e. worse for your alternative hypothesis. So see what is the largest negative value that the missing datapoint could take, add that value, and run 1 test (again, select the sidedness carefully). If the result is significant, then it would be even more significant for any other lower rank of the missing negative value. If that result is not significant, then this is inconclusive, and you have to rely on the test w/o that value, knowing that, depending on this 9th value, it may invalidate your conclusion obtained with only 8 values. Unsatisfactory, but...
